# SOAPUI mockservice: How to simulate throwing a connectException back to web service client?

Tags: web-services, web, integration-testing, soapui

How do I simulate throwing a connectException back to a web service client?

Comment: Have your tried with groovy?

Comment: I tried the following in groovy: throw new java.net.ConnectException("Connection refused"). Didn't work out. Could you maybe provide suggestions on how to better implement in groovy maybe?